# Angular 4 - How to get data from ASP.Net web api

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

Using the famous Visual Studio 2017 Angular 4 template, I tested the side navbar buttons and could fetch the in-memory data.

Then I added to the project, a new ASP.Net Core 2.0 API controller connected to a database using Entity Framework, and got it to run with the `200 HTTP GET` result.

The controller code:

```
#region TodoController
namespace TodoAngularUI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TodoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SchoolContext _context;
        #endregion

        public TodoController(SchoolContext DbContext)
        {
            _context = DbContext;

            if (_context.Todo.Count() == 0)
            {
                _context.Todo.Add(new Todo { TaskName = "Item1" });
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        #region snippet_GetAll
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Todo> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Todo.ToList();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        {
            var item = _context.Todo.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }
        #endregion
```

Now, I wanted to display the resulting ASP.Net Core controller data using Angular, so I created a TypeScript component named “`todo`” as below:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'todo',
    templateUrl: './todo.component.html'
})
export class TodoComponent {
    public Todo: task[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + '/api/todo').subscribe(result => {
            this.Todo = result.json() as task[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

interface task {
    Id: number;
    TaskName: string;
    IsComplete: boolean;
}
```

And created its HTML component as below:

```
<h1>Todo tasks</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching Todo tasks from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!todo"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table' *ngIf="Todo">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>Is complete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let Task of todo">
            <td>{{ Task.Id }}</td>
            <td>{{ Task.TaskName }}</td>
            <td>{{ Task.Iscomplete }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then went to add its routing in Nav side bar menu, here is TypeScript code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {
}
```

And here is Navbar HTML code:

```
<div class='main-nav'>
<div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
        <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
            <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </button>
        <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]="['/home']">TodoAngularUI</a>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                <a [routerLink]="['/home']">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                <a [routerLink]="['/counter']">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> Counter
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                <a [routerLink]="['/fetch-data']">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Fetch data
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                <a [routerLink]="['/api/todo']">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-apple'></span> Todo api
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

The issue here is that when I click the menu button to get data nothing happens, all other buttons are working but not this one, and 200 result is still showing when use directly the browser URL.

No error message, and I failed to find solution searching on the net for issues related to Non clickable buttons in Angular, and related to passing data from ASP.Net to Angular.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show your api code, also what is your controller? it is missing in the  http.get(baseUrl + '/api/todo')

Comment: @Haris, Updated the question.

Comment: which action are you invoking? GetAll?

Comment: Yes, the default one, just GetAll.

Comment: you need to define that in your ajax call as such http.get(baseUrl + '/api/todo/getall') try that

Comment: @Haris "/api/todo/getall" doesn't work, "/api/todo" is the right one since it gives 200 as http result.

Comment: ah okay, change this [Route("api/[controller]") to [Route("api/todo").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156779/discussion-between-sami-l-and-haris).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the template includes an example on how to do this - have you compared your 'Todo' solution with the one in the template?   Also, try `http.get(baseUrl + 'api/todo')` instead *(note the absence of `/` in front of `api`)* - the BASE_URL string should already include that.

Comment: @BenCottrell The template initially contains only a in-memory "Weather forecast" model example to show fetching data, and the BASE_URL doesn't contain "/" at the end, as you can see in the initial navbar html code above: the application to go to home page by using "/home"  and not "home"

Comment: @Sami-L Have you actually checked the content of BASE_URL to make sure that it doesn't contain `/` at the end?     The template may have changed again, but the last time I used it, the index.cshtml contained `<base href="~/" />` which means that BASE_URL should be suffixed with `/`.   Also, the client-side navigation with `router_link` directives doesn't use BASE_URL.     (BASE_URL isn't part of angular, it's just part of the template which reads the `href` attribute of the `base` tag).

Comment: @BenCottrell When I hover the cursor on the related button, the tool tip shows: http://localhost:xxxxx/api/todo where xxxxx is the port number set for IIS express

Comment: @Sami-L But what is the value of `BASE_URL`?   the URL from your `[routerLink]` button doesn't matter because that doesn't use `BASE_URL`

Comment: @BenCottrell you are right, sorry for this confusion since I've been lost between results given by VS 2017 and results given by VS code, Angular, and Angular CLI, etc ... many things are not working together. Currently through the browser developer tools I could find that the BASE_URL already contains '/' at the end. Another mistake I made is in the Nav bar HTML code, in the [routerLink]="['/api/todo']" should be [routerLink]="['/todo']". So please make your answer.

Comment: @Sami-L Done - I've tried to summarise the comments in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @BenCottrell, currently I have another issue with the same template, I get only a partial array. I'll ask the question in a separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Answer derived from my comments above)*

I have had a similar problem to this before using Microsoft's Angular 4 template.

---

#### The Problem

Microsoft provides the `BASE_URL` string as part of their template - it's obtained by extracting the `href` attribute from the `base` tag in `index.cshtml` (the BASE_URL string isn't part of the Angular framework).

The `base` tag in index.cshtml should look like `<base href="~/" />`

Which means that anywhere using `BASE_URL` in your Angular 4 project already has the BASE_URL suffixed with a `/` character.

So looking at this component calling `http.get` using that URL:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'todo',
    templateUrl: './todo.component.html'
})
export class TodoComponent {
    public Todo: task[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + '/api/todo').subscribe(result => {
            this.Todo = result.json() as task[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

Note that your call to `http.get(baseUrl + '/api/todo')` has a `/` in front of `/api/todo` - so the parameter passed into `http.get` will look like `http://example.com//api/todo` due to the extra `/` from BASE_URL.

---

#### The Solution

Try `http.get(baseUrl + 'api/todo')` instead (note the absence of `/` in front of `api/todo`) - the `BASE_URL` string should already include that, if nothing else in the template has been changed.

---

#### Update 22-03-2018: Using HTTP POST

As per the comment below, here's a quick example function for POST, assuming that `baseUrl` and `http` have both been injected into the constructor:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/rx';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'todo',
    templateUrl: './todo.component.html'
})
export class TodoComponent {
    constructor(private http: Http, 
        @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {
    }

    post(todo: Todo) {    
        let fullUrl = this.baseUrl + 'api/todo';
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.post(fullUrl, JSON.stringify(todo), options)
            .subscribe(result => {
                console.log(result);
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

And on the ASP.NET WebAPI side (which implicitly knows how to handle `Content-Type` of `application/json` in an HTTP POST request):

```
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Todo todo)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: And I was previously confused by this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjqcVugzX8U&t=2222s   at 57:40 it was showing clearly  http.get('/api/todo'), but this constructor was not including baseUrl.

Comment: How did you handle code related to post for the sample example?

Comment: @sam The code for POST is very similar - using `http.post` albeit with a JSON body (using `'Content-Type'` as `application/json`).    Have a look at `RequestOptions` and `Headers`.    The WebAPI controller will implicitly understand how to handle a POST request with Content-Type = application/json.    (don't forget to use the `[HttpPost]` attribute on the controller action)

Comment: I'm doing the same at the moment, but don't know why it's not hitting my controller.
Here's the brief code segment
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BankController : Controller
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public int SaveBankDetails([FromBody] Bank bank)
        {
        }
What do you think will be the correct url to hit this?

Comment: @sam It depends, are you receiving a 404 in your client?    I would think the URL for that would be either be `baseUrl + 'api/Bank/SaveBankDetails'` or `baseUrl + 'api/Bank'`.     I'd suggest you try testing your API using Postman, because it sounds like a Route issue with your controller - https://www.getpostman.com .  You could also try a `[Route("Bank/SaveBankDetails")]` attribute on your POST method too

Comment: @sam On an unrelated note, consider getting into the habit of returning an `IActionResult` from your action methods, because it makes error handling easier (particularly in a POST request when you will probably want validation and need to return a `BadRequest()` for any invalid data)

Comment: The status I'm seeing from Postman is 200 which means I am doing something silly which I can't figure out. I have also defined a route as per your suggestion and my postman url is
localhost:20500/api/Bank/SaveBankDetails
But still not hitting

Comment: @sam That sounds to me like it's working just fine.    Are you sure there's a problem with your code?    It could just be the debugger (for example, if you're trying to use the debugger in a release build then you need to switch to a Debug build)