# Angular showing only a part of the resulting data array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

Continuing the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756083/angular-4-how-to-get-data-from-asp-net-web-api), and after got a successful API result, I cannot get the html component to show the whole data array defined in the TypeScript component. Only one field is listed.

Here is the todo.component.ts file

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'todo',
    templateUrl: './todo.component.html'
})
export class TodoComponent {
    public todolist: todo[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl +'api/todo').subscribe(result => {
            this.todolist = result.json() as todo[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
// 
interface todo {
    Id: number;
    TaskName: string;
    IsComplete: boolean;
    queueing: number;
}
```

And here is the todo.component.html

```
<h1>To do List</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching tasks from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!todolist"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table' *ngIf="todolist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>Is complete</th>
            <th>queueing</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of todolist">
            <td>{{ item.Id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.TaskName }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.IsComplete }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.queueing }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The rendered HTML

[image: ![enter image description here]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: check your model's property names with backend and front end

Comment: is that a screenshot for ants? Sorry, I just had to say it.

Comment: @ZombieChowder sorry, I increased the screenshot size, is it ok now?

Comment: @Sami-L yes, it's just that I quoted "Zoolander" with my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please print the result of 'result.json()' in the console.

Anyway, attributes usually start with lowercase letter. Maybe the interface should be:

```
interface todo {
    id: number;
    taskName: string;
    isComplete: boolean;
    queueing: number;
}
```

with id, taskName and isComplete with lowercase, like the 'queueing' attribute.